# To migrate java web project from PrimeFaces 3.4 to PrimeFaces 5.2

Tags: jsf, primefaces, migration

I have not lot work experience with PrimeFaces. I have to migrate a java web PrimeFaces project from 3.4 to 5.2. Although I searched it all over the internet there was not proper solution for my situation. If you ever have any experience with this kind of problem or ever heard of that please let me know or send me link for that. Basically I want to the way of doing it. I already have idea about witch component should be changed. Is there anything to do except replacing the jar? I already tried to replace PrimeFaces 3.4 with PrimeFaces 5.2 jar. But it does not allow me to replace the jar. Do I have to to change the code too? Please i want the migration steps.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

There is a PrimeFaces migration guide. you need to go step by step to get from 3.5 to 5.2.

Here is the full migration guide for your situation:

Copied from [MigrationGuide](https://code.google.com/p/primefaces/wiki/MigrationGuide)

> **3.4 to 3.5**
>   **Component Changes**
>
> - DateSelectEvent, ScheduleDateSelectEvent, ScheduleEntrySelectEvents    classes are removed, use SelectEvent instead.
> - Column class in SortEvent and ColumnResizeEvent is replaced with    UIColumn to support dynamic columns.
> - Scrollable and Resizable DataTable-TreeTable features are reimplemented. DataTable and TreeTable no longer render cell container div element with classes ui-dt-c and ui-tt-c.
> - Sheet component is removed as it duplicated functionality of DataTable. Galleria is reimplemented.
>
> General Changes
>
> - IE7 support is phased out.
>
> **3.5 to 4.0 Component Changes**
>
> - MenuModel is rewritten and not backward compatible with the old version.
> - **(skip this when e.g. directly migrating from 3.x to 5.x, it is 'reverted' again in 5.0)** DataTable sortBy and filterBy expressions require the plain property    name meaning "name" instead of "`#{person.name}`".
>     Backward    compatibility is maintained for expressions like
>     "`#{var.property}`" but not for complex expressions.
> - FileUpload is reimplemented and it is backward compatible except "showButtons" option is removed.
> - disabledSelection option of column, moved to DataTable, change is    backward compatible and the option will be removed from column in a future release.
> - AutoComplete: removed process/global/onstart/oncomplete in favor of    "`p:ajax event="query`" process/global/onstart/oncomplete"
>
> General Changes
>
> - Preferred way of accessing widgets is via `PF('widgetVarName').show()`,    old way (e.g. `widgetVarName.show()`)
>     is still supported and will be removed in a future version.
>
> **4.0 to 5.0 Component Changes**
>
> - Chart components are deprecated in favor of new generic chart component with new Chart API. Old chart components are still supported but will be removed in a future release.
> - ToolbarGroup deprecated, use left and right facets of toolbar instead. (Reverted back as of 5.0.1, both facets and toolbar groups will be supported instead)
> - Defining fields in sortBy-filterBy attributes is deprecated use a value expression instead.e.g. `sortBy="#{user.name}`" instead of sortBy="name"
> - DataTable frozen rows feature take an integer value instead of a    collection from now on. This value defined how many rows from the start should be frozen.
> - LazyDataModel's filters parameter changed to Map instead of Map as a requirement of the new Advanced
>     Filtering Feature.
> - Dialog: appendToBody was removed in favor of `appendTo="@(body)`" to    gain more flexibility
> - Watermark: forElement was removed in favor of `for="@(yourSelector)"`.
> - Widgets must be referenced via "PF". e.g. `PF('widgetVarName').show()`    instead of `widgetVarName.show();`
> - DataTable layout changed to table-layout:fixed.
> - PrimeFaces Push is reimplemented, PushContext is deprecated, use    EventBus instead along with the new Push API.
> - ScrollPanel is reimplemented, usage is backward compatible however UI    is slightly different.
>
> **5.0 to 5.1**
>
> - Support for literal texts in filterBy-sortBy expressions were    deprecated in 5.0 and it is removed in 5.1. These attributes only work with value expression as in the past.
> - Deprecated chart components are removed.

Comment: thanks. for guide. Is there any things do i have to change except replacing the jar.when I tried to replace the jar, It would not allow to do that. Do I have to change some code too...????

Comment: Yes you need to change .jar file and change the code according to guide in my post.

Comment: when I replace the jar file it show message                                                          "Problem: The project uses the file/folder called "primefaces-3.4.RC1.jar", but this file/folder was not found.
Solution: Click Resolve and locate the missing file/folder."                          the project witch i"m working is huge. it has over 50 xhtml files so to be sure. this message is normal. or am I doing wrong plz let me know....

Comment: You need to remove old dependency (for primefaces 3.4) and add new dependency (for primefaces 5.2) and the error should go away.

Answer (score -1):

You can't directly migrate from 3.4 to 5.2.
There are some steps given to migrate in [MigrationGuide](https://code.google.com/p/primefaces/wiki/MigrationGuide). Perhaps you could first migrate from 3.4 to 4.0 there are some components changes on DataTable, DateSelectEvent, etc. Then you could proceed with 4.0 to 5.0 migration which involves more changes in LazyDataModel's and some of componets. Please go thought link given for MigrationGuide above.

Comment: You can migrate directly. You only have to take all migration steps into account at once. There are aven steps between 3.5 and 4 and then 4 and 5 that are the reverse of eachother. So a waste of time